# Javascript Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined" in PHP file upload script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a line in my file upload script (javascript portion) that gives me an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
```

The line in my javascript thats causing this problem is:

```
status.html(data.responseJSON.count + ' Files uploaded!').fadeIn();
```

Here is my full javascript function:

```
$(function() {
  /* variables */
  var status = $('.status');
  var percent = $('.percent');
  var bar = $('.bar');

  /* submit form with ajax request using jQuery.form plugin */
  $('form').ajaxForm({

    /* set data type json */
    dataType:'json',

    /* reset before submitting */
    beforeSend: function() {
      status.fadeOut();
      bar.width('0%');
      percent.html('0%');
    },

    /* progress bar call back*/
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(pVel);
      percent.html(pVel);
    },

    /* complete call back */
    complete: function(data) {
      status.html(data.responseJSON.count + ' Files uploaded!').fadeIn();
    }

  });
});
```

The script uses a PHP file uploader a produces a progress bar using JSON. The script works when I upload small files but when the files are over 10MB then it always gives me an error regardless of php.ini settings (I set it to 500MB on the php.ini config file).

Is there any limitations to file size using javascript that I don't know about?

EDIT: At the request of @Rodrigo I have my file upload script along with my form script below, the file upload php code is at the very bottom and gets executed using a PHP_SELF and isset(submit) functions to reduce the amount of files used (everything is documented):

```
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
     div#banner_left {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0%;
       left: 0%;
       width: auto;
     }
     div#banner_right {
       float: right;
       width: auto;
     }
    </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/structure.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner_left">
<img src="js/logo_ryerson.gif"/>
</div>
<div class="status"></div>
<br><br><div class="img">
<img src="/images/logo.png" />
</div><center><br><br>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
Choose Document Type:
<select name="document_type">
<option value="None">Pick Document Type</option>
<option value="Textbooks">Text Books</option>
<option value="Testbanks">Test Bank</option>
<option value="Notes & Assignments">Assignment/Notes</option>
</select><br>
Choose Course Code:
<select name="subject_list">
<option value="None">Pick Course</option>

<!-- FUNCTION TO SCAN DIRECTORY NAMES IN DROP DOWN LIST //-->

<?php
$dir = "./uploads";
$list = scandir($dir); /* This function sorts dirs */

$list = array_diff($list,array(".","..","index.php"));

foreach ($list as $file)
{
   if (!is_dir($file)) echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>\n";
}
?>
</select><br>
Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB): <input name="files[]" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
Upload Progress Bar<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
</div>
<H2>All Courses</H2></center><br>

<!-- THE FOLLOWING CODE IS FOR LISTING DIRECTORIES INSIDE UPLOADS FOLDER //-->

<?php
$dir = "./uploads";
$list = scandir($dir); /* This function sorts dirs */
$list = array_diff($list,array(".","..","index.php"));

echo "<ol>";
foreach ($list as $file)
{
   if (!is_dir($file)) echo "<li><a href='https://rye-high.ca/Rye High/$dir/$file'>$file</a></li>\n";
}
echo "</ol>";
?>
<!--FILE UPLOAD SCRIPT //-->

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$subject_list = $_POST['subject_list'];
$document_type = $_POST['document_type'];
$dir = "/var/www/rye-high-website/Rye High/uploads/$subject_list/$document_type/";
$count = 0;

// Error if no course code is picked
if ($subject_list == "None") {
echo '<br><div class="alert">Please Pick A Course Code</div>';
}
// Error No Document Type is picked
if ($document_type == "None"){
echo '<br><div class="alert">Please Pick A Document Type</div>';
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_FILES['files']))
{
  // loop all files
  foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name )
  {
    // if file not uploaded then skip it
    if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
      continue;

    // now we can move uploaded files
      if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $dir . $name) )
        $count++;
  }

  echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));

}
}
?>
```

Comment: It could be an issue the the TTL in the PHP.ini file. If you have large files, and you don't increase the (TTL, or time to live), the request might timeout before it's complete and cause an error.

Comment: php.ini has two size limit config options: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size that you might want to check

Comment: after adding the php.ini file have you restarted.. check it have you modified upload_max_filesize.. and the execution time is required more time so you have to increase the max_execution_time

Comment: Your helped work guys now my files get uploaded up to 500MB. I changed the POST max size to 500MB and TTL to 5000 seconds. However my javascript is still showing an error, I'd like to fix that if possible

Answer (score 2):

Your complete function should come with a second string parameter to avoid you try to catch a property from undefined attribute.

Your second parameter definition:

> string categorizing the status of the request ("success",
>   "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

Try something like this:

```
/* complete call back */
complete: function(data, status) {
  if(status === "success")
    status.html(data.responseJSON.count + ' Files uploaded!').fadeIn();
}
```

I think that your problem is from php, you should show us your php code or php problem.

Comment: Your code does not work since my status attribute does not call "success". Take a look at my PHP code above. Thanks again for the help

Comment: yes, it not work because your status isn't "success", but this avoid you try to use undefined value, and this is very important!

Comment: i've solved your main question, do you don't think that i deserve an up vote?

Comment: I still get the error even if I do complete: function(data, status) {
  if(status === "100%")
    status.html(data.responseJSON.count + ' Files uploaded!').fadeIn();
}

Comment: string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").